# VBA static time stamp only when cell data has changed--NOT when data refreshes. Standard VBA not working

Tags: vba, timestamp

I'm very new to VBA and will do my best to explain my issue.
I have a workbook that syncs a list of tasks bidirectionally with Outlook Tasks, and that's working just fine.
I also have a macro that creates a static times tamp every time the "Status" column (Column D) changes.
The problem is, every time I open the worksheet and it syncs with Outlook, it refreshes Column D (along with the rest of the worksheet) and the time stamp updates even if the Status text has remained the same.
Below is the macro I'm using to create the time stamp: is there a way to modify so it only time stamps when the actual text in the cell (Column D) changes (i.e. "In Progress" becomes "Waiting"), and not just when the workbook syncs and refreshes all the data?

Thank you so much!!!
REVISED CODE BELOW--This is the code that syncs with Outlook from "ThisWorkbook" in the "Microsoft Excel Objects" folder.

```
'--> Declare some constants
'Edit the constants below as needed so they correctly reflect the column number they appear in in the spreadsheet'
Const EXC_CLIENT = 1
Const EXC_SUBJECT = 2
Const EXC_START = 5
Const EXC_STATUS = 4
Const EXC_DUE = 8
Const EXC_EID = 26
Const PROC_NAME = "Outlook Synchronization"
'Do not change any constants from this point on
Const olTaskNotStarted = 0
Const olTaskInProgress = 1
Const olTaskComplete = 2
Const olTaskWaiting = 3
Const olTaskDeferred = 4
Const olText = 1
Const olYesNo = 6
Const olFolderTasks = 13
Const DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = &H1&

'--> Declare some variables
Dim olkApp As Object, _
    olkSes As Object, _
    olkFld As Object, _
    olkTsk As Object, _
    olkPrp As Object, _
    excWks As Excel.Worksheet, _
    lngRow As Long, _
    strRun As String, _
    bolSkp As Boolean

Private Sub InitializeExcel()
    Set excWks = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lngRow = 2
    strRun = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-nn-ss")
End Sub

Private Sub DeactivateExcel()
    Set excWks = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeOutlook()
    Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olkSes = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    olkSes.Logon olkApp.DefaultProfileName
    Set olkFld = olkSes.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
End Sub

Private Sub DeactivateOutlook()
    olkSes.Logoff
    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set olkSes = Nothing
    Set olkApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    '--> On saving the workbook you will be given an opportunity to synchronize from Excel to Outlook
    InitializeExcel     'Prep Excel for a sync
    InitializeOutlook   'Prep Outlook for a sync
    Excel2Outlook       'Sync from Excel to Outlook
    DeactivateExcel     'Clean-up Excel
    DeactivateOutlook   'Clean-up Outlook
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    '--> On opening the workbook you will be given an opportunity to syncronize data from Outlook to Excel
    bolSkp = False      'Set this to True if you don't want to be prompted to run the sync when opening/closing the spreadsheet.
    InitializeExcel     'Prep Excel for a sync
    InitializeOutlook   'Prep Outlook for a sync
    Outlook2Excel       'Sync from Outlook to Excel
    DeactivateExcel     'Clean-up Excel
    DeactivateOutlook   'Clean-up Outlook
End Sub

Private Sub Excel2Outlook()
    If Not bolSkp Then
        If MsgBox("Should I sync the tasks to Outlook?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_NAME) = vbYes Then
            Do Until excWks.Cells(lngRow, 1) = ""
                Select Case excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID)
                    Case ""
                        Set olkTsk = olkFld.Items.Add()
                        With olkTsk
                            .UserProperties.Add "ExcelTaskList", olYesNo, True
                            .UserProperties.Item("ExcelTaskList").Value = True
                            .UserProperties.Add "Synced", olText
                            .UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                            .Save
                        End With
                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) = olkTsk.EntryID
                    Case Else
                        Set olkTsk = olkSes.GetItemFromID(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID))
                End Select
                With olkTsk
                    .Subject = excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) & "/" & excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT)
                    If IsDate(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START)) Then .StartDate = excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START)
                    If IsDate(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE)) Then .DueDate = excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE)
                    Select Case excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS)
                        Case "Complete"
                            .Status = olTaskComplete
                        Case "Deferred"
                            .Status = olTaskDeferred
                        Case "In Progress"
                            .Status = olTaskInProgress
                        Case "Not Started"
                            .Status = olTaskNotStarted
                        Case "Waiting"
                            .Status = olTaskWaiting
                    End Select
                    olkTsk.UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                    .Save
                End With
                lngRow = lngRow + 1
            Loop
            For lngRow = olkFld.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set olkTsk = olkFld.Items(lngRow)
                Set olkPrp = olkTsk.UserProperties.Find("ExcelTaskList", True)
                If TypeName(olkPrp) <> "Nothing" Then
                    If olkTsk.UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value < strRun Then
                        olkTsk.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Outlook2Excel()
    Dim excRng As Excel.Range, arrTmp As Variant, intCnt As Integer
    If Not bolSkp Then
        If MsgBox("Should I sync tasks from Outlook?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_NAME) = vbYes Then
            For intCnt = olkFld.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set olkTsk = olkFld.Items(intCnt)
                Set olkPrp = olkTsk.UserProperties.Find("ExcelTaskList", True)
                If TypeName(olkPrp) = "Nothing" Then
                    'The task does not exist in the spreadsheet.  Add it.
                    lngRow = excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                    With olkTsk
                        If InStr(1, .Subject, "/") > 0 Then
                            arrTmp = Split(.Subject, "/")
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = arrTmp(0)
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = arrTmp(1)
                        Else
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = "Select Client"
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = .Subject
                        End If
                        If .StartDate <> #1/1/4501# Then
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START) = .StartDate
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START).NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm;@"
                        End If
                        Select Case .Status
                            Case olTaskComplete
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Complete"
                            Case olTaskDeferred
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Deferred"
                            Case olTaskInProgress
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "In Progress"
                            Case olTaskNotStarted
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Not Started"
                            Case olTaskWaiting
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Waiting"
                        End Select
                        If .DueDate <> #1/1/4501# Then
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE) = .DueDate
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE).NumberFormat = "[$-409]ddd, mmm. d;@"
                        End If
                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) = .EntryID
                        .UserProperties.Add "ExcelTaskList", olYesNo, True
                        .UserProperties.Item("ExcelTaskList").Value = True
                        .UserProperties.Add "Synced", olText
                        .UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                        .Save
                    End With
                Else
                    If olkTsk.UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value > olkTsk.LastModificationTime Then
                        For lngRow = 2 To excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                            If excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) = olkTsk.EntryID Then Exit For
                        Next
                        If lngRow >= 2 And lngRow <= excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
                            With olkTsk
                                If InStr(1, .Subject, "/") > 0 Then
                                    arrTmp = Split(.Subject, "/")
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = arrTmp(0)
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = arrTmp(1)
                                Else
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = "Select Client"
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = .Subject
                                End If
                                If .StartDate <> #1/1/4501# Then excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START) = .StartDate
                                Select Case .Status
                                    Case olTaskComplete
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Complete"
                                    Case olTaskDeferred
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Deferred"
                                    Case olTaskInProgress
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "In Progress"
                                    Case olTaskNotStarted
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Not Started"
                                    Case olTaskWaiting
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Waiting"
                                End Select
                                If .DueDate <> #1/1/4501# Then excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE) = .DueDate
                                .UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                                .Save
                            End With
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Critical problem.  There was no match in the spreadsheet for the task" & vbCrLf & vbTab & olkTsk.Subject, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, PROC_NAME
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            On Error Resume Next
            For lngRow = excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                If excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) <> "" Then
                    Set olkTsk = olkSes.GetItemFromID(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID))
                    Debug.Print excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT)
                    If (TypeName(olkTsk) = "Nothing") Or (olkTsk.Parent.Name = "Deleted Items") Then
                        Set excRng = excWks.Range("A" & lngRow, "Z" & lngRow)
                        excRng.Delete xlShiftUp
                    End If
                End If
                Set olkTsk = Nothing
            Next
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ForceExcel2Close()
    Dim varDesktop As Variant
    varDesktop = OpenInputDesktop(0, False, DESKTOP_READOBJECTS)
    'varDesktop will be 0 if the screen is locked, non-zero if it is not.
    If varDesktop = 0 Then
        bolSkp = True
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        CreateScriptFile
        RunScriptFile
    End If
End Sub

Sub CreateScriptFile()
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFil As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
    Set objFil = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Environ("TMP") & "\CloseExcel.vbs", True)
    With objFil
        .WriteLine "WScript.Sleep 5000"
        .WriteLine "Set excApp = GetObject(,""Excel.Application"")"
        .WriteLine "excApp.Quit"
        .WriteLine "Set excApp = Nothing"
        .Close
    End With
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFil = Nothing
End Sub

Sub RunScriptFile()
    Dim objShl As Object
    Set objShl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShl.Run Environ("TMP") & "\CloseExcel.vbs", 0, False
    Set objShl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: From the described behavior, a "refresh" without changing the content triggers a `Change` event. To circumvent this you might consider reading the status (col D) on `workbook_open`, and store it in a variable. Then allow the refresh, and look for differences with the initial value. It's a hack. Would it help?

Comment: Hi Floris, thanks for the comment. I'm open to anything at this point, but I don't have enuogh savvy to fully follow what you're saying. How do I store the data in Column D as a variable?

Comment: I have created a small working example - see my answer below.

Comment: In the process of updating, you have "lost" the original `Workbook_SheetChange()` event code. Consider putting it back for completeness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code implements the idea I talked about in my comment:

> Keep a copy of the data that you consider "unchanged", and when the
>   `SheetChange` event fires, compare the actual new value against the
>   reference. If the two values are not the same, take the action you
>   wanted to take.

**EDITED** Based on the first version of the code not working for your, I suspect that the refresh happens before the workbook_open event fires. To get around this, I have created a new variant, `initialized`, which will initially be `empty` (no value assigned to it). When the `SheetChange` event fires, it checks the state of this variable: if it is empty, it knows to do the initializing of the `colStore` before running the rest of the code. That ought to solve the problem. Otherwise the way this macro works is unchanged:

By keeping a copy of the data "before we messed with it" in memory, you prevent "updates" of the time stamp if the value didn't actually change.

It worked for a simple test case - when I "edit" a cell but put the same value back in, the "change" event is fired, but the date stamp is not updated.

Let me know if any of this needs further explanation.

```
Option Explicit
Dim colStore
Dim initialized
Const colOfInterest = "D2:D1000" ' make this the column you want to be active on
Dim rowOne As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  If IsEmpty(initialized) Then
    MsgBox "opening workbook. Nothing has been initialized yet"
    initializeIt
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub initializeIt()
  colStore = Range(colOfInterest).Value
  rowOne = Range(colOfInterest).Cells(1).Row
  initialized = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tempAddress
On Error GoTo leaveSub

If IsEmpty(initialized) Then
  MsgBox "fired sheet_change before workbook_open!"
  initializeIt
End If

With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Range(colOfInterest), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
            Else
                ' see if value actually changed
                tempAddress = .Row
                If .Value = colStore(.Row - rowOne + 1, 1) Then
                Else
                  colStore(.Row - rowOne + 1, 1) = .Value ' update the store
                  ' update the date:
                  With .Offset(0, 2)
                    .NumberFormat = "mmm, d, h:mm:ss AM/PM"
                    .Value = Now
                  End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
leaveSub:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**SECOND EDIT** Based on the code you have given, I think the following "code merge" should produce something that works. I cannot test it - but let me know if this works for you, or if you still have problems. There are some TEST MESSAGEs in here - take them out after everything works (they just help confirm that program flow is correct). Put all this code in the Workbook module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim colStore
Dim initialized
Const colOfInterest = "D2:D1000" ' make this the column you want to be active on
Dim rowOne As Integer

'--> Declare some constants
'Edit the constants below as needed so they correctly reflect the column number they appear in in the spreadsheet'
Const EXC_CLIENT = 1
Const EXC_SUBJECT = 2
Const EXC_START = 5
Const EXC_STATUS = 4
Const EXC_DUE = 8
Const EXC_EID = 26
Const PROC_NAME = "Outlook Synchronization"
'Do not change any constants from this point on
Const olTaskNotStarted = 0
Const olTaskInProgress = 1
Const olTaskComplete = 2
Const olTaskWaiting = 3
Const olTaskDeferred = 4
Const olText = 1
Const olYesNo = 6
Const olFolderTasks = 13
Const DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = &H1&

'--> Declare some variables
Dim olkApp As Object, _
    olkSes As Object, _
    olkFld As Object, _
    olkTsk As Object, _
    olkPrp As Object, _
    excWks As Excel.Worksheet, _
    lngRow As Long, _
    strRun As String, _
    bolSkp As Boolean

Private Sub InitializeExcel()
    Set excWks = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lngRow = 2
    strRun = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-nn-ss")
End Sub

Private Sub DeactivateExcel()
    Set excWks = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeOutlook()
    Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olkSes = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    olkSes.Logon olkApp.DefaultProfileName
    Set olkFld = olkSes.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
End Sub

Private Sub DeactivateOutlook()
    olkSes.Logoff
    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set olkSes = Nothing
    Set olkApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    '--> On saving the workbook you will be given an opportunity to synchronize from Excel to Outlook
    InitializeExcel     'Prep Excel for a sync
    InitializeOutlook   'Prep Outlook for a sync
    Excel2Outlook       'Sync from Excel to Outlook
    DeactivateExcel     'Clean-up Excel
    DeactivateOutlook   'Clean-up Outlook
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'--> Adding a few lines of code to capture the "current status"
'--> before anything gets updated / refreshed
If IsEmpty(initialized) Then
    MsgBox "TEST MESSAGE. Opening workbook. Nothing has been initialized yet."
    initializeIt
  End If
'--> On opening the workbook you will be given an opportunity to syncronize data from Outlook to Excel
    bolSkp = False      'Set this to True if you don't want to be prompted to run the sync when opening/closing the spreadsheet.
    InitializeExcel     'Prep Excel for a sync
    InitializeOutlook   'Prep Outlook for a sync
    Outlook2Excel       'Sync from Outlook to Excel
    DeactivateExcel     'Clean-up Excel
    DeactivateOutlook   'Clean-up Outlook
End Sub

Private Sub Excel2Outlook()
    If Not bolSkp Then
        If MsgBox("Should I sync the tasks to Outlook?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_NAME) = vbYes Then
            Do Until excWks.Cells(lngRow, 1) = ""
                Select Case excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID)
                    Case ""
                        Set olkTsk = olkFld.Items.Add()
                        With olkTsk
                            .UserProperties.Add "ExcelTaskList", olYesNo, True
                            .UserProperties.Item("ExcelTaskList").Value = True
                            .UserProperties.Add "Synced", olText
                            .UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                            .Save
                        End With
                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) = olkTsk.EntryID
                    Case Else
                        Set olkTsk = olkSes.GetItemFromID(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID))
                End Select
                With olkTsk
                    .Subject = excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) & "/" & excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT)
                    If IsDate(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START)) Then .StartDate = excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START)
                    If IsDate(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE)) Then .DueDate = excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE)
                    Select Case excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS)
                        Case "Complete"
                            .Status = olTaskComplete
                        Case "Deferred"
                            .Status = olTaskDeferred
                        Case "In Progress"
                            .Status = olTaskInProgress
                        Case "Not Started"
                            .Status = olTaskNotStarted
                        Case "Waiting"
                            .Status = olTaskWaiting
                    End Select
                    olkTsk.UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                    .Save
                End With
                lngRow = lngRow + 1
            Loop
            For lngRow = olkFld.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set olkTsk = olkFld.Items(lngRow)
                Set olkPrp = olkTsk.UserProperties.Find("ExcelTaskList", True)
                If TypeName(olkPrp) <> "Nothing" Then
                    If olkTsk.UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value < strRun Then
                        olkTsk.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Outlook2Excel()
    Dim excRng As Excel.Range, arrTmp As Variant, intCnt As Integer
    If Not bolSkp Then
        If MsgBox("Should I sync tasks from Outlook?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_NAME) = vbYes Then
            For intCnt = olkFld.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set olkTsk = olkFld.Items(intCnt)
                Set olkPrp = olkTsk.UserProperties.Find("ExcelTaskList", True)
                If TypeName(olkPrp) = "Nothing" Then
                    'The task does not exist in the spreadsheet.  Add it.
                    lngRow = excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                    With olkTsk
                        If InStr(1, .Subject, "/") > 0 Then
                            arrTmp = Split(.Subject, "/")
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = arrTmp(0)
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = arrTmp(1)
                        Else
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = "Select Client"
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = .Subject
                        End If
                        If .StartDate <> #1/1/4501# Then
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START) = .StartDate
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START).NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm;@"
                        End If
                        Select Case .Status
                            Case olTaskComplete
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Complete"
                            Case olTaskDeferred
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Deferred"
                            Case olTaskInProgress
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "In Progress"
                            Case olTaskNotStarted
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Not Started"
                            Case olTaskWaiting
                                excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Waiting"
                        End Select
                        If .DueDate <> #1/1/4501# Then
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE) = .DueDate
                            excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE).NumberFormat = "[$-409]ddd, mmm. d;@"
                        End If
                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) = .EntryID
                        .UserProperties.Add "ExcelTaskList", olYesNo, True
                        .UserProperties.Item("ExcelTaskList").Value = True
                        .UserProperties.Add "Synced", olText
                        .UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                        .Save
                    End With
                Else
                    If olkTsk.UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value > olkTsk.LastModificationTime Then
                        For lngRow = 2 To excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                            If excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) = olkTsk.EntryID Then Exit For
                        Next
                        If lngRow >= 2 And lngRow <= excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
                            With olkTsk
                                If InStr(1, .Subject, "/") > 0 Then
                                    arrTmp = Split(.Subject, "/")
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = arrTmp(0)
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = arrTmp(1)
                                Else
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_CLIENT) = "Select Client"
                                    excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT) = .Subject
                                End If
                                If .StartDate <> #1/1/4501# Then excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_START) = .StartDate
                                Select Case .Status
                                    Case olTaskComplete
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Complete"
                                    Case olTaskDeferred
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Deferred"
                                    Case olTaskInProgress
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "In Progress"
                                    Case olTaskNotStarted
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Not Started"
                                    Case olTaskWaiting
                                        excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_STATUS) = "Waiting"
                                End Select
                                If .DueDate <> #1/1/4501# Then excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_DUE) = .DueDate
                                .UserProperties.Item("Synced").Value = strRun
                                .Save
                            End With
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Critical problem.  There was no match in the spreadsheet for the task" & vbCrLf & vbTab & olkTsk.Subject, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, PROC_NAME
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            On Error Resume Next
            For lngRow = excWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                If excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID) <> "" Then
                    Set olkTsk = olkSes.GetItemFromID(excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_EID))
                    Debug.Print excWks.Cells(lngRow, EXC_SUBJECT)
                    If (TypeName(olkTsk) = "Nothing") Or (olkTsk.Parent.Name = "Deleted Items") Then
                        Set excRng = excWks.Range("A" & lngRow, "Z" & lngRow)
                        excRng.Delete xlShiftUp
                    End If
                End If
                Set olkTsk = Nothing
            Next
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ForceExcel2Close()
    Dim varDesktop As Variant
    varDesktop = OpenInputDesktop(0, False, DESKTOP_READOBJECTS)
    'varDesktop will be 0 if the screen is locked, non-zero if it is not.
    If varDesktop = 0 Then
        bolSkp = True
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        CreateScriptFile
        RunScriptFile
    End If
End Sub

Sub CreateScriptFile()
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFil As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
    Set objFil = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Environ("TMP") & "\CloseExcel.vbs", True)
    With objFil
        .WriteLine "WScript.Sleep 5000"
        .WriteLine "Set excApp = GetObject(,""Excel.Application"")"
        .WriteLine "excApp.Quit"
        .WriteLine "Set excApp = Nothing"
        .Close
    End With
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFil = Nothing
End Sub

Sub RunScriptFile()
    Dim objShl As Object
    Set objShl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShl.Run Environ("TMP") & "\CloseExcel.vbs", 0, False
    Set objShl = Nothing
End Sub

'--> And the other functions (that initialize the data store, and update status
Private Sub initializeIt()
  colStore = Range(colOfInterest).Value
  rowOne = Range(colOfInterest).Cells(1).Row
  initialized = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tempAddress
On Error GoTo leaveSub

If IsEmpty(initialized) Then
  MsgBox "fired sheet_change before workbook_open!"
  initializeIt
End If

With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Range(colOfInterest), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
            Else
                ' see if value actually changed
                tempAddress = .Row
                If .Value = colStore(.Row - rowOne + 1, 1) Then
                Else
                  colStore(.Row - rowOne + 1, 1) = .Value ' update the store
                  ' update the date:
                  With .Offset(0, 2)
                    .NumberFormat = "mmm, d, h:mm:ss AM/PM"
                    .Value = Now
                  End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
leaveSub:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Third (and last?) edit** Updated code to allow multiple columns to be "tracked". This is quite a bit more general; in order to keep things simple I am posting just the functions that changed - replace them in the above code, and it should work for both columns D and J. If you look at the comments it's easy to see what you would have to modify if you want different behavior.

```
Option Explicit
Dim colStore
Dim initialized
' two strings that contain the columns and range of rows we want to track:
' columnsOfInterest_string could contain any number of comma-separated columns
' but rowsOfInterest_string must contain just two: first and last row
Const columnsOfInterest_string = "D,J"
Const rowsOfInterest_string = "2,1000"

' a few variables that get initialized when workbook is first opened
Dim rowsOfInterest
Dim colLookupTable
Dim rangeOfInterest As Range

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  If IsEmpty(initialized) Then
'    MsgBox "opening workbook. Nothing has been initialized yet"
    initializeIt
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub testIt()
  Dim r1, r2, ra, rd, rad
  Dim vals, valUnion, valBlock
  ra = "A1:A5"
  rd = "D1:D5"
  rad = ra & "," & rd
  Debug.Print rad
  Set r1 = Range("A1:A5")
  Set r2 = Range("D1:D5")
  vals = Range(rad).Value
  valUnion = Union(r1, r2).Value
  valBlock = Range("A1:D5").Value
End Sub

Private Sub initializeIt()
' copy the data from the relevant ranges to a variable
' if the cell contents don't change, don't update the time stamp
  Dim thisCol, rangeAddress, cList, rRange
  Dim nRows, nCols, c, ci, ri

  ' create a "dictionary" to go from "column name" to "column index in stored array"
  Set colLookupTable = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  ' get the list of columns as an array:
  cList = Split(columnsOfInterest_string, ",")
  nCols = UBound(cList) + 1 ' since Option Base 0

  rowsOfInterest = Split(rowsOfInterest_string, ",") ' should be just two numbers
  nRows = Val(rowsOfInterest(1)) - Val(rowsOfInterest(0)) + 1

  ' create a string with the address of the entire range of interest:
  rangeAddress = ""
  ci = 1
  For Each c In cList
    thisCol = c & rowsOfInterest(0) & ":" & c & rowsOfInterest(1)
    colLookupTable.Add c, ci    ' create lookup for index into the array
    rangeAddress = rangeAddress & thisCol & ","
    ci = ci + 1
  Next c
  rangeAddress = Left(rangeAddress, Len(rangeAddress) - 1)
  Set rangeOfInterest = Range(rangeAddress)
  ' get all the data from the complete range and store it
  colStore = ToArray(rangeOfInterest)
  initialized = True
End Sub

Function ToArray(rng) As Variant()
' With thanks to Tim Williams of StackOverflow.com
' answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18994211/1967396

Dim arr() As Variant, r As Long, nr As Long
    Dim ar As Range, c As Range, cnum As Long, rnum As Long
    Dim col As Range

    nr = rng.Areas(1).Rows.Count
    ReDim arr(1 To nr, 1 To rng.Cells.Count / nr)
    cnum = 0
    For Each ar In rng.Areas
        For Each col In ar.Columns
        cnum = cnum + 1
        rnum = 1
        For Each c In col.Cells
            arr(rnum, cnum) = c.Value
            rnum = rnum + 1
        Next c
        Next col
    Next ar

    ToArray = arr
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tempAddress, colOfInterest
On Error GoTo leaveSub

If IsEmpty(initialized) Then
'  MsgBox "fired sheet_change before workbook_open!"
  initializeIt
End If

With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(rangeOfInterest, .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
            Else
                ' see if value actually changed
                tempAddress = Split(Target.Address, "$")
                colOfInterest = colLookupTable(tempAddress(1))
                If .Value = colStore(.Row - rowsOfInterest(0) + 1, colOfInterest) Then
                Else
                  colStore(.Row - rowsOfInterest(0) + 1, colOfInterest) = .Value ' update the store
                  ' update the date:
                  With .Offset(0, 2)
                    .NumberFormat = "mmm, d, h:mm:ss AM/PM"
                    .Value = Now
                  End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
leaveSub:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but it's not yet working, though it could be a problem with my implementation. Below is the code for the worksheet, including a calendar module I'm using:

Comment: Hmmm, it won't let me post my code in the comment section due to character limit, and it won't let me post by "Answering my own question". Apologies, this is my first time working with stackoverflow and I am bumbling a bit!

Comment: it's still refreshing/overwriting the timestamp when I open the workbook (which automatically syncs it with Outlook). If there was a way for me to attach my file to present a better understanding I would but it doesn't seem to be an option on StackOverflow. I appreciate your willingness to help but I have a feeling my abilities are too nascent to take your help and implement it! Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Don't worry! You can add your code by editing your own question. I suspect (this was my worry) that Excel does the refresh before firing the "workbook_open" event. I have modified my code above - you should see one of two messages when the workbook first opens. It you get the "fired sheet_change before workbook_open" message we will know we found (and fixed...?) the issue. Let me know how it goes.  PS - this code needs to be in the Workbook code module, but I think you already know that (otherwise you would not get any event processing).

Comment: Eeek! I was not aware it belongs in the workbook code. When I said my abilities were nascent I was being charitable. When I add your code to the bottom of the existing code in the Workbook, the Option Explicit becomes nested in the Private Sub above it and separated from your code above; when I add it to the top, it seems to interfere with the pre-existing "Declaration of constants". I will revise my original post with the pre-existing code from the workbook. Please let me know if this is where your code belongs, and if it should go above or below it. Apologies for my ineptitude!

Comment: "Option Explicit" is good programming practice and belongs at the top of every module. It ensures that you declare all your variables - and will warn you (sometimes) about mistyped variable names (since they were probably not declared). Recognize that you can only have one Workbook_Open and Workbook_SheetChange sub in this module - so if you are doing other things as well you need to do some merging. Once you post your code I can help more.

Comment: Updated code - can't test this now since I don't have your data etc; let me know if this works.

Comment: The empty-check approach is better anyway, as it will also correctly handle a code reset.

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks. Right now the challenge is to get the code into OP's workbook correctly...

Comment: @Floris so appreciative of the help. I wiped out the code in the Workbook module and pasted in your modified code above. When I open the file, I get your Test Message first, then I'm prompted to sync, and when I do it still cascades the time stamp column with the current date/time overwriting the time stamp from before. One quick question--you keep referencing the workbook "module". To be clear, I am posting this in the "ThisWorkbook" page under Excel Objects. I do have another folder called "Modules", and in it is "Module1", but that only contains a small piece of code for my pop-up calendar

Comment: Wait! I removed my original time stamp code from the worksheet (Page 1), and now it seems to be working! By Jove, Floris--I think you've done it! 1000 thank you's!

Comment: Two little questions then I will close this case and, if I may, send you an Amazon gift card. 1) to remove the Test Message, what line should I delete from the code? 2) If i wanted the time stamp to fire not just when the data changed in column D, but when the data changed in columns B, D or J--is that a matter of adding a range to the Option Explicit at the top of the code? If I'm pressing my luck just send me packing and I will be quite happy.

Comment: No worries. The `const colOfInterest` describes the range you look for; but right now the code thinks it is all in one column. If you want to look at multiple columns it will take a little bit more work - especially when they are not contiguous. Can't update the code with that tonight, sorry. As for the messages - just put an apostrophe in front of the line that starts `MsgBox` and it will go away. You can't send me a gift card - but you can "pay it forward" by looking at other questions and seeing if there are any you can answer. Appreciate the positive feedback! Glad to help.

Comment: Understood. I will expand my macro knowledge (VBA for Dummies, maybe) and try to return the favor to another in need. And in terms of my request, forget Column B. Columns D and J and the ones. I know I'm asking a lot so I will try to keep my promise to pay it forward...

Comment: I noticed that you had declared some constants that correspond to specific column numbers - `EXC_STATUS = 4` for example, corresponding to column `D`. I don't see a constant corresponding to column `J` (would be `10`). If the columns you want to "track" have an associated number I know a way to extend this solution. I could hard code the number - it would be better to use the defined constants. What would column `J` be called?

Comment: I would call Column J "Notes" to keep things simple.

Comment: I have made an edit that shows how to extend this to multiple columns. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: Implemented your new code. Going well. Only hitch is when I update column J it time-stamps in column L instead of Column F (looking to have both triggers timestamp in same column). So just need to offset time stamp target for Column J by -4...trying to figure out how to do it...

Comment: Instead of `with .Offset(0,2)` using `with Cells(.Row, 6)` ought to work. I think- on iPhone can't check.

Comment: All seems to be working well. Thank you @Floris Truly appreciative of your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You might want to mark the answer as "accepted" using the check mark alongside it. Good luck on your learning journey!