# Excel VBA to create an array from non adjacent ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I couldn't quite find the answer to my question, but if there is another post I am missing, please, let me know. I am trying to add values to a dynamic array using range.value. The problem is that the cells I want to add to the array are not adjacent/contiguous. The array is created but it is only (1 to 2, 1 to 1). Here is the code I am using to test how to do this:

```
Sub Ranges()

    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Sheets(1).Range("I1:I2,K1:K2,M1:M2,O1:O2").Value

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            Debug.Print i, j, arr(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to loop through the range areas to build up the array.

Comment: Or search array from non-contiguous range here on SO... there are several hits.

Comment: @BigBen - I tried the steps in the link and I was still ending up with a one-dimensional array. Not sure why Excel is treating my array as one dimensional? I declared the array as variant, but I never defined the rows,columns. Not sure if that matters?

Comment: That question creates a 1d array... Do you want a 2D array?

Comment: Yes, I need a 2D array.

Comment: I have 4 total columns "I", "K", "M", "O" and the number of rows will be dynamic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993915/get-values-from-union-of-non-contiguous-ranges-into-array-with-vba-with-a-simple for a 2D array.

Comment: @BigBen - That did it! Thanks so much for your help!