# Referencing only visible rows in a filtered table - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am working on a project for selecting films. It contains a table of films, with columns for the name of the film and other data, such as IMDB ratings etc. I've written a macro which filters the table according to user input (e.g. minimum IMDB rating), and now I would like to select a random film from the filtered table.

I can work out the number of visible films with:

```
FilmCount = FilmsSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
```

And generate a random number from this with:

```
Randomize
FilmNumber = Int(FilmCount * Rnd) + 1
```

However, selecting a random film from the filtered table is more difficult; in a non-filtered table I could simply use the random number to select a film with:

```
Film = FilmsSheet.Cells(FilmNumber + 1, 1)
```

But in a filtered table, the rows don't ascend numerically due to the missing filtered rows, for example 1,3,4,7...

How can I use the random number to select the corresponding film in the filtered table? Thanks.

Comment: Create an array from the visible rows and then pick a random film from there.

Comment: @BigBen that makes sense, thanks - although I'm still unsure how to create an array from the filtered data only? `Films = FilmsSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value` only creates an array with the table headers in, as the filtered rows are not continuous. If there is an easy way to do this please let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993915/get-values-from-union-of-non-contiguous-ranges-into-array-with-vba-with-a-simple... you need a loop basically.

Comment: You could collect the filtered row numbers sequentially into a collection object, and then randomly pick a number from the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @BigBen's commented suggestion, I iterated through all the rows in the table, and if they were visible added the film name to an array, from which a random film could be picked:

```
'=====Select random film from visible=====
Dim FilmCount As Integer: FilmCount = FilmsSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
Dim Films() As Variant
ReDim Films(1 To FilmCount)

x = 1
Dim r As Integer: r = 2
Do Until FilmsSheet.Cells(r, 1) = 0
    If Not FilmsSheet.rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        Films(x) = FilmsSheet.Cells(r, 1)
        x = x + 1
    End If
    r = r + 1
Loop

Randomize
Dim FilmNumber As Integer: FilmNumber = Int(FilmCount * Rnd) + 1

MsgBox (Films(FilmNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

Assume that the Film Title (header column) is cell C1, and data is already filtered

```
Sub test()
Set rngFilmTitle = Range("C2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
X = Application.Transpose(rngFilmTitle)
Do
rndNum = Int(Rnd() * UBound(X))
Loop
End Sub
```

If for example the total Film Title (in filtered data) is 4 film title,
If you F8 again and again and again in the loop, the rndNum result will give random number  between 0 to 3 (see from the Locals Window in VBA editor).

If you already sure about that, then you can remove the loop, 
then have

```
rndNum = Int(Rnd() * UBound(X))
FilmTitle = X(rndNum) '---> this will give a random film title.
```

That's if I'm not mistaken to get what you mean, because your title question seems that you want to get a random from the hidden rows (unfiltered rows), but in the body of your question it seems that you want to get a random from the visible rows (filtered rows) ?