# Creating variant array from union of ranges

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I want to create a variant array when using a union to join ranges.

If I select one of the ranges the variant array will work.
When I union, I only receive the row dimensions and not the column dimensions.

For example,

```vb
Sub arrTest()
    
    'Declare varbs
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim myRng As Range
    
    'Assign varbs
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).row
       Set myRng = Application.Union(.Range("G3:G" & lRow), .Range("J3:O" & lRow), .Range("AD3:AE" & lRow), .Range("AI3:AI" & lRow))
        
        myArr = myRng.Value2
         
    End With
```

Will return a variant of
myArr(1, 1)
myArr(2, 1)
myArr(1, 3)

However if I were to select one of the ranges within the union for example:

```vb
Sub arrTest()
    
    'Declare varbs
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim myRng As Range
    
    'Assign varbs
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).row
       Set myRng = .Range("J3:O" & lRow)
        myArr = myRng.Value2
         
    End With
```

I properly get
myArr(1, 1)
myArr(1, 2)
myArr(1, 3)
etc.

How do I return the column dimensions as well, without looping through the sheet?

Comment: You can't read a non-contiguous range into an array - it just doesn't work.

Comment: @TimWilliams any suggestions for a workaround, or better to just re-order columns so that they are contiguous?

Comment: You can loop over the range and fill an array

Comment: Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993915/get-values-from-union-of-non-contiguous-ranges-into-array-with-vba-with-a-simple

Comment: @TimWilliams i currently loop over the range in the worksheet to fill the array, but was looking to speed this process up by filling the array as a whole block

Comment: If you size the final array you can fill it from each of the areas in your source range: if you read each area into an array then the performance should still be good.

Comment: @TimWilliams The first part is easy- The final array has the dimensions(1 to 3, 1 to 10). rng1 will fill arr1 (t to 3, 1 to 3); rng2 will fill arr2(1 to 3, 1 to 6); rng3 will fill arr3(1 to 3, 1 to 1). 

I then need to fill the final array with each i.e. arr1 = final_arr(1 to 3, 1 to 6); arr2 = final_arr(1 to 3, 7 to 9); arr3 = final_arr(1 to 3, 10 t0 10). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Sub ArrayTest()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr, lrow As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    arr = GetArray(ws.Range("G3:G" & lrow), ws.Range("J3:O" & lrow), _
                   ws.Range("AD3:AE" & lrow), ws.Range("AI3:AI" & lrow))
        
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
        .Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
    End With
         
End Sub

'Given a number of input ranges each consisting of one or more columns (assumed all input ranges have
'  the same # of rows), return a single 1-based 2D array with the data from each range
Function GetArray(ParamArray sourceCols() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim arr, rng, numCols As Long, numRows As Long, r As Long, c As Long, tmp, col As Long
    
    numRows = sourceCols(0).Rows.Count
    'loop over ranges and get the total number of columns
    For Each rng In sourceCols
        numCols = numCols + rng.Columns.Count
    Next rng
    
    ReDim arr(1 To numRows, 1 To numCols) 'size the output array
    c = 0
    For Each rng In sourceCols        'loop the input ranges
        tmp = As2DArray(rng)          'get range source data as array ####
        For col = 1 To UBound(tmp, 2) 'each column in `rng`
            c = c + 1                 'increment column position in `arr`
            For r = 1 To numRows      'fill the output column
                arr(r, c) = tmp(r, col)
            Next r
        Next col
    Next rng
    GetArray = arr
End Function

'Get a range's value, always as a 2D array, even if only a single cell
Function As2DArray(rng)
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        As2DArray = rng.Value
    Else
        Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        arr(1, 1) = rng.Value
        As2DArray = arr
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Excellent mate. Thankyou. Will tweak abit to suit my needs, but is exactly what I am tryin to achieve

Comment: this falls apart when I have one row.  Any recommendation on how to fix this. I have made a couple attempts however I can see that value2 as an array and not sure how to loop through value2 itself. If i can do that then I can assign to the array

Comment: Calling `.Value` on a range which is only a single cell doesn't give you a 2D array: you can use a helper function to ensure you always get a 2D array from any range.

Comment: the value2 of my second range in sourcecols looks like
`Value2(1) Value2(1, 1) Value2(1, 2) etc
`

Comment: Did you try the updated code above?

Comment: Just saw it. Perfect Appreciate the assistance